# How to make end Icon drawable tooltip in TextField jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have textfield and end drawable which is info type. When I click on that I want to open this tooltip look like this. Anyone guide me how can I make like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw this using Path and set it as shape of your Composable or check this [speech bubble library](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Speech-Bubble) i built. In demo section you can test with other properties. You can use BubbleLayout or BubbleColumn.

And use it as

```
BubbleColumn(
        bubbleState = rememberBubbleState(
            backgroundColor = DefaultBubbleColor,
            alignment = ArrowAlignment.BottomRight,
            arrowShape = ArrowShape.TRIANGLE_ISOSCELES,
            arrowWidth = 25.dp,
            arrowHeight = 20.dp,
            cornerRadius = 8.dp,
            shadow = BubbleShadow(elevation = 1.dp),
            padding = Padding(8.dp)
        )
    ) { Text(text = message) }
```

And show with as we show any Dialog with a mutableState with Boolean flag

```
var showInfo by remember {mutableStateOf(false)}

if(showInfo){
  Bubble...
}
```

Comment: I created a shape with a rounded rect base and an arrow at the middle: https://gist.github.com/SylpheM/1da000b0044ff5c60d8537e5f26d7f2d

It can be tweaked to add an offset to the arrow. 
Hope it can help others!